# How do I prevent Cocoa from calling drawRect on every completely invisible sub-view

Tags: cocoa, nsview, drawrect, nsscrollview

I have a completely working, very fast, single window app, written in Objective-C and originally developed on MacOS 10.7 using XCode 4.  It has a single scroll view showing portions of one large content view with many sub-views.  Only a portion of each sub-view shows, and only that sub-view that is initially visible gets its `-drawRect` method called when the app shows the initial window.  The content view being scrolled and all of its sub-views and sub-sub-views are created programmatically when the app launches (not from the xib file).

Each sub-view usually has a variety of controls and one special sub-classed sub-sub-view that displays a computationally intensive drawing that gets precomputed and cached the first time its `-drawRect` method is called.  So scrolling through all this distributes the computation and caching until just when the user needs to see it.  This all works well and has done so for years.  None of the sub-sub-views' `-drawRect` methods is ever called until the sub-sub-view has a portion of itself that becomes visible within the hierarchy during scrolling.

The problem is that I've now ported the app to XCode 9.3 and MacOS 10.13.4, and have discovered that after the single window with the scrolling view in it is shown for the first time at launch on the desktop, every sub-sub-view is having its `-drawRect` method called by Cocoa's runtime, even though *none* of the sub-sub-views are even spatially close to being visible in the view hierarchy inside the scrolling view in the window.  This causes every one of the sub-sub-views to pre-compute and cache, all before the user can interact with the just-launched app.  This takes many seconds, which is unacceptable user-interface-wise.

I have no idea what my unchanged code might be doing to cause all the invisible sub-sub-views to be asked to draw themselves, and so it seems this new state of affairs could be due to some later Apple framework behavior changes.  I've tried querying the `-isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor` property of the sub-sub-view inside `-drawRect`, but it is always returning false, probably because the super-views are logically visible but being clipped by the scrolling view.

How does one debug this situation, which seems completely contrary to what the view system is supposed to be doing automatically?  Under what circumstances does the system call a view's `-drawRect` when the view's frame is completely unable to show anything?  Did something change on Apple's framework side?

Comment: I assume it's a typo that you write you ported your app to "MacOS 10.4".

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be MacOS 10.13.4.

Comment: You can edit it, you know. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to "responsive scrolling", which was introduced in 10.9 and is only enabled for apps linked against the 10.8 SDK or later. The best consolidated documentation is probably in the [10.9 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_9Scrolling). Be sure to read the section on "overdraw" a bit down the document, too, which (if I'm right) is the specific cause of your invisible views being asked to draw.

The quick-but-dirty way to prevent this is to have the class of one of the involved views override `+isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling` to return false.

But, it may be better to do the computation asynchronously on a background thread. Your view would draw some cheap placeholder (or nothing) until the computation is completed. At completion, you'd mark it as needing display. (Be sure to shunt all UI work from the background thread back to the main thread.)

You could also defer the creation of your subviews (or sub-subviews) and use an override of `-prepareContentInRect:` to create them as necessary. Or use an override of that method to disable overdraw as described in the release notes.

Comment: I believe you are correct re responsive scrolling.  But I tried implementing the class method `isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling` in the ScrollView, in the DocumentView it is scrolling, in the sub-views it brings into and out of view, and in their sub-sub-views as well.  The only time any of these methods was called was in the top-level ScrollView that I've sub-classed.  The behavior did not change regardless of returning either YES or NO.

Comment: Another interesting thing I found.  The window in the xib file was marked Visible At Launch.  So I turned that off and programmatically made it visible at the end of the App Delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, by calling the window's `makeKeyAndOrderFront` method.  After doing this, only the first five or six still-invisible sub-sub-views were having their `-drawRect` method called by the responsive scrolling system, instead of all of them (hundreds in my case).  So that is progress, but doesn't really answer the question.