# Updating an NSView with processing in a separate thread

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

Suppose you have a scrollable `NSView`. When you scroll it, the part coming into the clipping rectangle will need to be refreshed, and the view's `drawRect` (Swift `draw`) method will be called for a rectangle containing that new part. Suppose now that before that part can be drawn, some time-consuming processing will need to be done. Since you don't want to burden the main thread (from which `drawRect` is called) with that processing, you might want to unload it on a secondary thread. Now my question is, what's a good way to do this? For example, you can:

- Initiate asynchronous processing from `drawRect`, exit it without drawing, and have the secondary thread, when it's finished, store the data somewhere and call `setNeedsDisplay` and thus have `drawRect` get called again.
- As above, but when the processing is finished, draw into the view directly (in the main thread), without going through `drawRect`.
- Set `canDrawConcurrently` for the view beforehand; but that, as far as I can tell, will not necessarily force `drawRect` into a secondary thread, unless the system decides to do so.

Or, maybe some other way? This seems like a common enough situation, but I can't find any tips on how to do this in a clean way.

Comment: Is the content of the NSView dynamic and can it change over time when the user is scrolling the NSView? The solution will depend on how dynamic or static the content is. The question is also what type of content it is. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Related question: [How do I prevent Cocoa from calling drawRect on every completely invisible sub-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309774/how-do-i-prevent-cocoa-from-calling-drawrect-on-every-completely-invisible-sub-v)

Comment: @MacUserT: it's not dynamic. I am thinking of displaying the visualization of a sound using potentially slow spectral analysis. A map application would be a somewhat similar example.

Comment: @Willeke, I'm adding the suggestion in the link to the list above. Thanks (Ed.:) Actually I take it back. That is the same suggestion as my first one, with the addition of immediately drawing a placeholder until the computation is done.

Comment: How about `prepareContentInRect`?

Comment: @Willeke, That is called in the main thread, just before `drawRect`, so I don't know that it would be any advantage.